# Need StatusStrip to fill its items from Right to Left

Tags: c#, winforms

When I add a StatusStrip to the form and start creating some labels inside it, they show from helf to right, Is there a way I can show them from Right to left inside this statusstrip?

Comment: Doesn't the `RightToLeft=Yes;` property do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the following property:

```
statusStrip1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Alignment` property in the designer from 'Left' to 'Right'.

Comment: but it doesn't have this property called "Alignment"

Comment: The answer you accepted was for the entired status strip. This wasn't your question. Your question was how to alligh the controls within the status strip.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was confusing. But still I clicked both on the status bar and on the controls inside it, can't find a property called "Alignment".